# I have a question about point wise convergence concerning Lebesgue measurable sets.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

If I have a sequence $\{E_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ of $\mathcal{M}$-measurable sets, and $E=\cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$. How can I show that $\chi_{E_n} f\rightarrow\chi_Ef$ pointwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that the $E_n$ are increasing (otherwise it is false).

If $x\in E$, then $\chi_{E_n}(x) = 0$ as long as $x\notin E_n$, and then $\chi_{E_n}(x) = 1$.

This happens for every $x\in E=\cup E_n$.

If $x\notin E$, then $x\notin E_n$ and the sequence stays at 0.

In every case, $$\chi_{E_n}(x)f(x)\to \chi_{E}(x)f(x)
$$

Comment: Can you elaborate why $\chi_{E_n}(x)f(x)\to \chi_{E}(x)f(x)$ when x is in E. I don't get the argument that since its $0$ some times and $1$ sometimes when have convergence.

Comment: it is first 0, then 1 and never back to 0 (if the $E_n$ are increasing).

Comment: I understand, because if x is in $E_{n_0}$ for some $n_0$ then x is in $E_n$ for $n\ge n_0$. correct?

Comment: Correct! ()()()()